# Bad receiver type "Bool"

Tags: objective-c, json, boolean

I have a problem with parsing with my server, specially the variable that I add. it doesn't let me to add it. the error message is "Bad receiver type "Bool"(aka "bool")"

here is my code :

```
@interface MessagingKeyServerResponse : NSObject <NSCopying>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSData *key;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *keyId;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *validityStart;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *validityEnd;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL support_long_messages;


@end



@interface MessagingKeyServerResponse ()


// added support_long_messages for parsing
-(instancetype)initWithKey:(NSData *)key keyId:(NSString *)keyId validityStart:(NSDate *)validityStart validityEnd:(NSDate *)validityEnd support_long_messages:(BOOL)support_long_messages;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@implementation MessagingKeyServerResponse

// steve note: added message long characters

-(instancetype)initWithKey:(NSData *)key keyId:(NSString *)keyId validityStart:(NSDate *)validityStart validityEnd:(NSDate *)validityEnd support_long_messages:(BOOL)support_long_messages
{
    if (!key) {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"No key"];
        return nil;
    }

    if (!keyId) {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"No key id"];
        return nil;
    }

    if (!validityStart) {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"No validity start"];
        return nil;
    }

    if (!validityEnd) {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"No validity end"];
        return nil;
    }


    if (!support_long_messages) {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"there is no support long Characters"];
        return nil;
    }



    if (!([validityStart compare:validityEnd] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Invalid validity range"];
        return nil;
    }



    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _key = [key copy];
        _keyId = [keyId copy];
        _validityStart = [validityStart copy];
        _validityEnd = [validityEnd copy];
        _support_long_messages = [support_long_messages copy] ;


        if (!_key || !_keyId || !_validityStart || !_validityEnd || !_support_long_messages) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

so the error that I receive from  _support_long_messages when I want to assign :

_support_long_messages = [support_long_messages copy] ;

any help appreciate.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL support_long_messages; try this.

Comment: No, doesn't work in my function, the problem Is not a variable, it is a parameter that not assign in copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
_support_long_messages = support_long_messages;
```

`BOOL` is a value type, assignment already creates a copy.
Explicit copy is necessary only for reference types (objects).